# @JsonKey Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to make MainResponse class which is returned from backend with same format. I have created a Data class and the object it has should be generic `json key` regarding the class name like below:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:style/api/response/status_response.dart';

part 'data.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(genericArgumentFactories: true)
class Data<T> {

  @JsonKey(name: T.toString())
  T? returnedObject;
}
```

what I wanted to do is giving JsonKey name value as class name. but i am receiving following error:

```
Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
```

is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: it would be very nice to see an examples of json, that you recieve from backend, say {"some_key": "some_value"}, so that it would be clearer what are u trying to acieve

Comment: actually I implemented it by editing mainresponse.g.dart file. just used T.toString().toLowerCase() for key value :) @DanilaFominyh then it worked!

Comment: cool :D_________ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, the question was easy. just try to edit `classname.g.dart` file which is auto generated. and use'T.toString().toLowerCase()'instead of auto generated key.